# How to count the sum of the results after iterating peer-to-peer, excluding repetitions

Tags: python, loops

From the result of my function, i receive a score for aligment n sequences ignoring the repeats E.g for 5 sequences:

```
1 vs 2 = 11
1 vs 3 = 322
1 vs 4 = -132
1 vs 5 = -22
2 vs 3 = -5
2 vs 4 = 169
2 vs 5 = 222
3 vs 4 = -140
3 vs 5 -16
4 vs 5 = 111
```

And stores them in a list:

```
my_list = [11, 322, -132, -22, -5, 169, 222, -140, -16, 111]
```

I would like to sum all the results where the sequence appeared and make a new list out of it. Summation example:

S1 = 11+322-132-22 = 179

S2 = 11-5+169+222 = 397

and so on

```
new_list = [179, 397, 161, 8, 295]
```

Is there any simple way to create a function that would be flexible for a different number of sequences and do it?

Comment: How does `new_list` has 5 values?

Comment: Because we are comparing 5 sequences in this example and in this list is the sum of the scors for each of them. No, i have only a list of scors.

Comment: Can you please check values in my_list, they do not match with your top calculation.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see the mistake. Where exactly does it fit? S3= 322-5-140-16=161, S4= -132+16-140+111=8, S5= -22+222-16+111=295

Comment: `222` is written as `22` and `111` is written as `11`?

Comment: Ahhh sorry. Yes, my bad. Now it should be ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your sequence length is `n` (=5 here).
Use:

```
def f(n, my_list)
   arr = np.zeros((n, n))
   mask = np.tril(np.ones((n, n))) == 0
   arr[mask] = my_list
   new_list = np.sum(arr + arr.T, axis = 1)
```

Output:

```
>>> new_list
array([179., 397., 161.,   8., 295.])
```

Comment: Could you please see for me what is wrong with mask as it is getting synatax error but i don't know how to correct